# When to use は as a topic marker instead of わ?

Tags: grammar

I just learned that は is pronounced the same as わ ("wa"), instead of "ha" when it's used as a topic marker. But I couldn't properly find information about the grammatical rules in place to decide when to write わ or は in sentences. Could anyone explain to me when should I use one or the other?

I believe the example below is correctly using は, but why?

> お母{かあ}さんの車{くるま}**は**それです。

Thanks in advance.

---

PS.: I just noticed after the first answer that I got really confused when I was studying the subject, people don't use わ as a topic marker in sentences. But it seems that it's too late and now I'm not allowed to delete the question anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The topic marker is always written as は and always pronounced as わ. There isn't a case where you'd *write* the topic marker as わ.